# How can I change terminal branch color?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, git, pop-os

My terminal has output like the one below.

`pc@pop-os:~/my-project (main)$`

This project was downloaded via GitHub. `(main)` is colored green. I set it as a branch name that appears on my terminal when I go to the project's directory. When I make a change, I want the terminal to recognize the change and change the `(main)` color to red. Does anyone who can help with that, please?

Comment: Are you using zsh?

Comment: No, I am using bash @EdgarMagallon

Comment: Do you use ohmybash or any other plugin/framework to customize your shell? Btw , what is the output of `echo $PS1`

Comment: I am not using anything. Output of PS1 is `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[32m\]$(parseGitBranch) \[\033[00m\]\$\n>`

Comment: @SerdarAKYOL I think PopOs has installed some framework to customize your shell like that. Can you show us the output of `type -a parseGitBranch`  I'm not sure if this will show some output.

Comment: No @EdgarMagallon. I added `parseGitBranch`. Inside that function has `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'` command. I wrote that to extract branch name

Comment: @SerdarAKYOL thank you! That's useful. I'm thinking in a possible solution but as Quasimodo said, it may be slow in very large projects.

Comment: "I want the terminal to recognize the change" The terminal is not going to _recognize_ anything. The terminal's job is to blindly execute the commands it receives. If it's asked to paint in green, it'll paint in green. If it's asked to paint in red, it'll paint in red. You have to configure your _shell_, that's the one emitting these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `parseGitBranch` function to define the colors. Your function should look like this:

```bash
parseGitBranch () {

   if ! git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null; then
      return 
   fi
   branch="($(git branch --show-current))"

   local STATUS
   STATUS=$(git status --porcelain)
   if [ -n "$STATUS" ]; then
      echo -e "\033[38;5;1m $branch" #red
   else
      echo -e "\033[38;5;34m $branch" #green
   fi
}
```

And you should set `PS1` to:

```bash
PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\$(parseGitBranch) \[\033[00m\]\$\n>"
```

The code above could be inside `~/.bashrc`.

**Explanation**

The following line will check if current directory is a **git project**:

```bash
   if ! git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null; then
      return 
   fi
```

I've changed your code `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'` to `git branch --show-current`. That's an easier way to get the current branch name.
Now, if the condition above is true then the function will check the status for the current git directory.
The most effective way to know if there are changes in your project is using `git status --porcelain`. So if you don't have any changes the output of `git status --porcelain` will be empty.
With `-n "$STATUS"` checks if the length of STATUS is nonzero.

If `-n $STATUS` is true then the branch color will be red (because you have changes): `echo -e "\033[38;5;1m $branch" #red`.
If it's false then the branch color will be green: `echo -e "\033[38;5;34m $branch" #green`.

You can check [this link](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) for more information about bash colors and formatting. Maybe your terminal doesn't support some formatting or the colors will not be printed correctly.

Comment: That's quite good. Thank you so much for the explanation. I wanted to give +1 but like I have less than 15 reputations, I couldn't.

Comment: @SerdarAKYOL no problem! Glad this works for you.